# How to populate a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict in this format:

```
names = ['Luis','Andres','Carlos']
my_dict = {'Name': names, 'Age'=['----']*len(names),'Address':['----']*len(names)}
```

I get the rest of the data through a request, using 'Name' as the input, like this:

```
for i in range(len(my_dict['Name'])):
            data = request(my_dict['Name'][i]) # I got a list
            my_dict['Age'][i] = data[0]
            my_dict['Address'][i] = data[1]
```

But I'm looking for a more idiomatic way to do it.

Edit: The dictionary is a temporary object to store the data, the final purpose is to save the data as a csv file and I thought a dictionary would be a good way to do it, in this particular case all names are unique. I'm looking for a pure python solution without any external libraries such as pandas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. If you have a lot of data in `names` and want to avoid rehashing, etc, then this is the most efficient way I can think of:

```
names = ['Luis','Andres','Carlos']
numnames = len(names)
my_dict = {'Name': names, 'Age'=[0]*numnames,'Address':[0]*numnames}

for i,name in enumerate(names):
    age, addr = request(name)
    my_dict['Age'][i] = age
    my_dict['Address'][i] = addr
```

Here's a more idiomatic way of storing the data (assuming all names are unique):

```
class Stats:
    def __init__(self, age=None, address=None):
        self.age = age
        self.address = address

data = {}
for name in names:
    age, addr = request(name)
    data[name] = Stats(age, addr)
```

Comment: what would be the advantage of defining a class against using for example, a tuple?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez: it makes your code more readable. For instance, it's clearer what you're trying to do, when you say `item.age` as opposed to `item[0]`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget this is what `collections.namedtuple` is for.

Answer (score 2):

Why not build the dict as you loop?

```
names = ['Luis','Andres','Carlos']
my_dict = {'Name': [], 'Age': [], 'Address': []}
for name in names:
    data = request(name)
    my_dict['Name'].append(name)
    my_dict['Age'].append(data[0])
    my_dict['Address'].append(data[1])
```

Or depending on your use case (I can't think of too many reasons *not* to use one of these latter solutions), why not make:

1. A dict with the name as a key and a (named)tuple of age and address as the value.

   - `{'Luis': (<age>, <address>), 'Andres': (<age>, <address>), ...}`
2. A list of dicts with name, age and address key-value pairs.

   - `[{'Name': 'Luis', 'Age': <age>, 'Address': <address>}, {...}, ...]`
3. A list of namedtuples of name, age and age.

   - `[('Luis', <age>, <address>), ...]` (namedtuples, so can be accessed via dot notation)

If you feel like you should be looping over the people instead of *just* names or *just* ages, you should use one of the three solutions I provided. If you're 100% sure you need to access all the ages at once, regardless of whose ages they are, then your solution is ok.

Comment: @JaredGoguen You're right question isn't clear enough, in this case names are unique.